# FWLSE3034E: The application "App name" for the runtime "runtime name" does not exist in the Worklight administration database

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am getting the following error when compile and build the App pointing to remote server.

I was checking the server configuration, everything looks correct.

It began showing the error when implementing Post Notifications functions.

MobileFirst plugin in Eclipse = 6.3.0

```
BinaryDownload E   FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found.                             
com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.exceptions.NotFoundException: FWLSE3034E: The application "App name" for the runtime "runtime name" does not exist in the Worklight administration database.
The database may be corrupted.

at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.BinaryDownloadService.getEntity(BinaryDownloadService.java:493)
at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.BinaryDownloadService.getContentObject(BinaryDownloadService.java:561)
at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.BinaryStorageBaseService.retrieveOrInfoImpl(BinaryStorageBaseService.java:115)
at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.BinaryDownloadService.__retrieveAppThumbnail__(BinaryDownloadService.java:169)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor227.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67) 
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54) 
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22) 
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:43)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
```

Comment: The obvious question is, did you first deploy the appname-all.wlapp file to the remote server?

Comment: And if you do see it, then it sounds like you're pointing to the wrong server?

Comment: Yes, I deploy the files in the following order:
> appname-all.wlapp
> appname-common.wlapp
> appname-android-version.wlapp
> appname-iphone-version.wlapp

I am sure that I am pointing to the correct server.

Comment: Looks like a sync issue. If you restart the server and then try accessing, do you see the same error?

Comment: @HelenoJimenez, see Vivin's question above.

Comment: @VivinK I already restart the server, but the result was the same.

Comment: I am trying to subscribe a User/Device to allow it receive notifications. I have not been able to subscribe it.  
When trying in localhost, I am able to subscribe the User/Device, but when trying in a remote server I am unable.

I am not sure if the following message is part of the problem.

> 000000bb SystemOut     O com.worklight.analytics.api.AnalyticsHttpService.sendDataToURL target server response code: 401

Comment: @HelenoJimenez does not sound related. 401 related to security while yours is more like a 404. Any news here?