# The application "App name" for the runtime "runtime name" does not exist in the Worklight administration database

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Mobile first 6.3
Java 7, Hybrid application.

we are encountering the same issue as mentioned in the below questions. I don't have reputation to add a comment to the same question.

[FWLSE3034E: The application "App name" for the runtime "runtime name" does not exist in the Worklight administration database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667428/fwlse3034e-the-application-app-name-for-the-runtime-runtime-name-does-not-e)
Please advice how did you resolve it.

Our issue is, we can receive push notification in both iOS and Android. in iOS when we click the notification we are able to traverse to the app, but in Android, when we click the  notification it does not launches the app, and sometimes we don't receive notification at all in android untill we restart the server.

Kindly advice.

Thanks.
@Martijin As I mentioned in my Ques itself, it is a duplicate, but since I don't have credits to comment on asking what is the status, I posted it as a new question and I myself have mentioned that it is like the same question by mentioning the link. Thanks.

Comment: Have you changed the name of the application in strings.xml ( changed it from what was defined when the application was generated in MF studio).

Comment: Thanks Vivin. It worked. Forget to reply back.

Comment: The issue is the changes haven't reflected, and the solution that worked is, in local we cleaned the server, and cleared the bin folders and changed the name in strings.xml  and android manifest and it worked.